# What is the difference between SQLite and xerial JDBC driver for SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

What are differences when using original SQLite and xerial JDBC driver SQLite?

SQLite is written in C to use it in Java. I have downloaded xerial JDBC driver for sqlite 3.8.6. Can I expect that it will have the same functions as original sqlite? So everything what is in the official documentation for version 3.8.6 is the same for JDBC version?

Answer (score 0):

`xerial/sqlite-jdbc` is just Java bindings for the C SQLite 3 library; it's a thin layer of code that takes the C API of SQLite and makes them available to Java code.

Comment: Sorry but i dont know what exactly is Java bindings. Does it mean that i have full access to the features of sqlite 3 library which is wrapped inside JDBC API?